# CsvHelper list of missing fields

Tags: c#, csvhelper

Borrowing from this post - [CSVHelper mandatory fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26712912/csvhelper-mandatory-fields). Let's say I have this code:

```
public sealed class DataMapper : CsvClassMap<DataType>
{
    public DataMapper()
    {
        Map(m => m.Field1).Name("FirstField");
        Map(m => m.Field2).ConvertUsing(m => { return 0; }); // required field
        Map(m => m.Field3).ConvertUsing(m => { return 1; }); // required field
    }
}
```

If I try to load a csv file and Field2 and Field3 are missing, how can I get a list of the missing fields? I know I can check for the existence of the field in the ConvertUsing statement, but if I throw an exception I'll only get one at a time.

I've looked at HeaderValidated and MissingFieldFound, but when they are mapped they don't get handled by those methods as far as I can tell.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a field called Errors and did all of the validation inside of that mapping.

```
Map(m => m.Errors).ConvertUsing(m => { 
    // do a bunch of validation
    return "all of the errors";
});
```

It felt like duplicate work because I still need validation on the ConvertUsing statements for my real fields, but this worked and turned out okay.